# Java8: Create list of object using enum value

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of enum like this :

```
public enum Fruit {
   Apple,
   Mango,
   Banana,
   kiwi
}
```

and I have class like this

```
public class FruitShop {
    private String name;

    public FruitShop(String name) {
       this.name = name
}
```

I want to create a list of object of FruitShop class passing each enum as an arument

```
List<FruitShop> shoplists = new new ArrayList<>()
shoplists.add(Fruit.Apple.name())
shoplists.add(Fruit.Mango.name())
shoplists.add(Fruit.Banana.name())
shoplists.add(Fruit.kiwi.name())
```

How can I achieve this using java8 stream?

Comment: did you try something? what didn't work? and does `shoplists.add(Fruit.Apple.name())` work with your existing code?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `EnumSet` with `stream` like this:

```
List<FruitShop> shoplists = EnumSet.allOf(Fruit.class).stream()
        .map(f -> new FruitShop(f.name()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Fruit.values()` then map to create `FruitShop` and collect as list

```
List<FruitShop> shoplists = Stream.of(Fruit.values())
                                  .map(f -> new FruitShop(f.name()))
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: ...or use `Arrays.stream(Fruit.values())`

Comment: or `EnumSet.allOf(Fruit.class).stream()`

Answer (score 0):

Other approach:

```
Arrays.stream(Fruit.values())
        .map(Fruit::name)
        .map(FruitShop::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```